# hide links from users or show them without query part

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP/html application where I send information based on dynamic queries to a different page like:

`menu_feat.php?inc=e2s_pb&op=list_del&e2s_hs_dest_hs=ssdgs.nejo&e2s_hs_id=10`

For security reasons we don't want to show the query part of the URL but something like:

`menu_feat.php?inc=e2s_pb' or better just 'menu_feat.php?`

How can I do this? Also I've seen some sites that shows links as:

`menu_feat.php?inc=JHUI5yyvb6tb978tb923zbs3ndynsa92n2sn123n`

How can I map the URL that includes the query portion to an URL like the one above? I've been trying Apache rewrite but didnt find a good way to handle it.

Comment: mod_rewrite is the best way to go for this.

Comment: I think that websites that you seen do it like this : They save that big crazy link at their database and get inc variable and search in their database and give a true answer or redirect

Comment: Can you be more specific? the query part is ´unknown´ until user hits Enter or click the submit button or the link. For using mod_rewrite I should know before hand the query portion in order for apache do the rewrite?

Comment: The last one might just be base64-encoding of a normal set of parameters.